# How to filter and Search a table with ngFilter?

Tags: html, angularjs, search, data-binding, filter

I have seen many examples and tutorials about table search and tried to work. The issue is that it search only the table results which is seen in the current page. What I mean is, I have used pagination and the search filer works only in page that is visible to the user. It doesn't get the results in other paginated pages.

I have implemented a simple search, which is explained in almost every example. Why my approach behave like this? Help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's my table.html

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
       <div class="input-group input-icon">
           <input id="empid" ng-model="Search.empid" type="text" class="form-control" name="empid" placeholder="Search with ID">
           <span class="input-group-addon">
               <i class="fa fa-search s14"></i>
           </span>
       </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
       <div class="input-group input-icon">
           <input id="ename" ng-model="Search.fname" type="text" class="form-control" name="ename" placeholder="Search with Name">
           <span class="input-group-addon">
               <i class="fa fa-search s14"></i>
           </span>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="row">                                   
   <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
    View <label>
           <span>
            <select class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="viewBy" ng-options="x for x in nums" ng-change="setEmployeesPerPage(viewBy)"></select>                                                            
            </span>
       </label> records at a time.
   </div>                             
<table id="basic-datatables" class="table table-bordered table-hover" cellspacing="0" width="100">
   <thead style="text-align:match-parent">
       <tr>
           <th rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width:100px">
               <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="table-links" ng-click="sortType='empid'; sortReverse=!sortReverse">
                   <span ng-show="sortType != 'empid'" class="fa fa-unsorted"></span>
                   <span ng-show="sortType == 'empid' && !sortReverse" class="fa fa-sort-asc"></span>
                   <span ng-show="sortType == 'empid' && sortReverse" class="fa fa-sort-desc"></span>
                ID</a>
           </th>
           <th rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width:200px">
               <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="table-links" ng-click="sortType='fname'; sortReverse=!sortReverse">
                   <span ng-show="sortType != 'fname'" class="fa fa-unsorted"></span>
                   <span ng-show="sortType == 'fname' && !sortReverse" class="fa fa-sort-asc"></span>
                   <span ng-show="sortType == 'fname' && sortReverse" class="fa fa-sort-desc"></span>
               First Name</a>
           </th>
           <th rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width:200px">
               <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="table-links" ng-click="sortType='lname'; sortReverse=!sortReverse">
                   <span ng-show="sortType != 'lname'" class="fa fa-unsorted"></span>
                   <span ng-show="sortType == 'lname'&& !sortReverse" class="fa fa-sort-asc"></span>
                   <span ng-show="sortType == 'lname'&& sortReverse" class="fa fa-sort-desc"></span>
               Last Name</a>
           </th>
           <th rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width:200px">Email</th>
           <th rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width:100px">Mobile</th>
           <th rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width:200px">Designation</th>
           <th rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width:200px">Dept. Name</th>
       </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
       <tr ng-click="selectRow(emp)" ng-repeat="emp in employeeDetails.slice(((currentPage-1)*itemsPerPage),((currentPage)*itemsPerPage)) | filter:Search | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse" style="text-align:match-parent">
           <td>{{emp.empid}}</td>
           <td>{{emp.fname}}</td>
           <td>{{emp.lname}}</td>
           <td>{{emp.email}}</td>
           <td>{{emp.mobile_no}}</td>
           <td>{{emp.designation}}</td>
           <td>{{emp.department_name}}</td>
       </tr>
   </tbody>
</table> 
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12">
       <uib-pagination total-items="totalEmployees" ng-model="currentPage" ng-change="pageChanged()" max-size="maxSize" boundary-links="true" class="pagination" items-per-page="itemsPerPage"></uib-pagination>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here's my controller.js

This is how I get the JSON.

```
(function initController() {

    EmployeeService.GetEmpDetails(function (res) {
        $scope.employeeDetails = JSON.parse(res.data);
    });
})();
```

How can I properly implement it. Thanks

Comment: You should first search and then filter. Right now you are doing is first limiting then searching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ng-repeat="emp in employeeDetails 
    | filter:Search 
    | limitTo: itemsPerPage : (currentPage-1)*itemsPerPage 
    | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse"
```

Try this.. First filter then limit.

Comment: The pagination is not working for your answer. It is broken :(

Comment: `limitTo : itemsPerPage : (currentPage-1)*itemsPerPage` change your formula of limit to this